# Display grid cell in a different background color if the entry exists in json file (on ReactJS)

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a table here that displays years and vehicle models in a grid format.

[image]

I would like the corresponding box to be blue if the entry for that vehicle model and year exists in the "coverage" segment of the json that I have below. And grey if it doesn't exist.

How could I dynamically achieve this without hardcoding/repeating the style for each of these cells?
Here's my code:

```
export default function Grid() {
  
    return (
        <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><img src={logo} alt="logo" className="logo"/></th>
      <th className="years">2018</th>
      <th className="years">2017</th>
      <th className="years">2016</th>
      <th className="years">2015</th>
      <th className="years">2014</th>
      <th className="years">2013</th>
      <th className="years">2012</th>
      <th className="years">2011</th>
      <th className="years">2010</th>
      <th className="years">2008</th>
      <th className="years">2007</th>
      <th className="years">2006</th>
      <th className="years">2005</th>
      <th className="years">2004</th>
      <th className="years">2003</th>
      <th className="years">2002</th>
      <th className="years">2001</th>
      <th className="years">2000</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td className="vehicule-models">ILX</td>
      <td className="coverage"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the json file:

```
{
  "vehicle-models": ["ILX", "MDX", "RDX", "RLX", "TL", "TLX", "TSX"],
  "years": [2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010],
  "coverage": {
    "ILX": [2017, 2016, 2015, 2014],
    "MDX": [2017, 2016, 2015, 2014],
    "RDX": [2011, 2010],
    "RLX": [2012, 2011, 2010],
    "TL": [2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010],
    "TLX": [2016, 2015, 2014, 2013],
    "TSX": [2017, 2015]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is already so repetitive!  We can clean it up majorly by looping through the data.

First make sure that you have `"resolveJsonModule": true` in your `tsconfig.json` file.  The imported JSON will interpret `coverage` as on object with keys `'ILX'`, etc.  But the `models` are just `string`.  So I've refined the type with `as (keyof typeof coverage)[]` to avoid index signature errors.

We loop through the array of `years` to create the header.  We loop through the array of `models` to create the rows.  For each cell, we see if `coverage[model].includes(year)` and return a different `className` depending on that.

```
import json from "./data.json";

export default function Grid() {
  const { years, coverage } = json;
  const models = json["vehicle-models"] as (keyof typeof coverage)[];

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <img src="" alt="logo" className="logo" />
          </th>
          {years.map((year) => (
            <th key={year} scope="col" className="years">
              {year}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {models.map((model) => (
          <tr key={model}>
            <th scope="row" className="vehicule-models">
              {model}
            </th>
            {years.map((year) => (
              <td
                key={year}
                className={
                  coverage[model].includes(year) ? "coverage" : "no-coverage"
                }
              />
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Style to you heart's content.

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-grid-table-from-json-file-3rq3i?file=/src/App.tsx)